I can't find a short sci-fi horror story about a solitary man on a desolate planet
I've been trying to find this story for ages. It is a short story I read in a small anthology, around 2012, but I think it's much older. I got it out of my middle school library. None of the other stories really scared me so much, so when I call it horror, I might be exaggerating, or maybe it's more horror in the way where there's a feeling of dread/hopelessness or humans are monsters when afraid way. Like a "wow, we think humans are good because we aren't being pushed."
I don't remember too much of the plot, but this was an era where space travel was common. There's only one guy, who goes to the planet, and finds something in the dark, and shoots it. Its one of those stories where his reaction, shooting it, causes the horror to follow. But I can't remember exactly what that was. I faintly remember him being sent to the planet on a job, already knowing it was kind of dangerous. But I'm not certain.
I really vividly remember either the cover of the book, or the intro illustration to that particular short story having a spaceman facing away from the viewer on the left side, angled so he's looking at something in the distance on the right side. The planet is pretty barren in the picture, and on the right side, further back, there's a small pile of rocks and a hint that something's behind them.
Also, I don't know how helpful this is, but my brain tied it together with the story from "scary stories to tell in the dark" about the man who shoots his toes off, because the moonlight on his nails made them look like eyes. May be nothing.
I've already tried reading through all of Philip K. Dick, and Ray Bradbury's short stories synopsis and it wasn't them. Also just read through the synopsis of the top horror sci Fi short stories on Google.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You mention that the horror follows the explorer's action, but do you remember if it there was a real threat or was it all in his imagination?  If real, was it a physical threat or mental/psychic?  Did the explorer survive?

I think he survived, and I think it was more about the fear of a threat driving him to do something awful, like firing without confirming what he was firing at. Also, sorry. Should have said this before, it's not "a walk in the dark" by Arthur C. Clark.

Hmmm. Isn't there a Fredric Brown story like this?
